# Handle Failed to launch '<URL>' because the scheme does not have a registered handler. via javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to open facebook messenger app via click to url using a tag

check in [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8c0qavs9/)

but I'm trying to handle via javascript the error if the app is not installed by changing to another compatible url

> Failed to launch
> 'fb-messenger://share?link=https://new-tabimuse.test/post/f12b51ae-23b6-4180-a3de-616c710263ed'
> because the scheme does not have a registered handler.

I'm trying by using `window.location` with onClick event via javascript but I can't handle the error

how can I do this?